# Convert Date to POSIXct

Tags: r, date, posixct

Why does the Date below change to "2014-07-07" when converted to POSIXct?

```
Sys.setenv(TZ='America/Sao_Paulo')
d <- as.Date("2014-07-08", format="%Y-%m-%d")
d
[1] "2014-07-08"
as.POSIXct(d)
[1] "2014-07-07 21:00:00 BRT"
```

Comment: Could this be related to the time zone? What if you supply a specific time zone when calling `as.POSIXct(d, tz = "...")`?

Comment: @beginneR I wanted to know the reason why that happens, I already have a workaround.

Comment: Maybe because of this (from `?as.POSIXct`): "Dates without times are treated as being at midnight UTC."

Comment: What is a fromat? :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Because `as.POSIXct.Date` doesn't look for a timezone (and won't pass it to `.POSIXct` if you specify it in `...`) and Date objects are "UTC", so your `POSIXct` is offset from the UTC of the Date object.

It would be better to call `as.POSIXct` on the character string directly, if you can:

```
> as.POSIXct("2014-07-08", format="%Y-%m-%d")
[1] "2014-07-08 BRT"
```

Comment: ...or convert the Date to `character` first: `as.POSIXct(format(d))`

Comment: Thanks, Joshua. That's strange, there is a `(...)` argument but it is not passed to `.POSIXct`, and passing a simple timezone paramater would solve this `.POSIXct(unclass(d) * 86400, tz="UTC")`

Comment: @CarlosCinelli: I'm not sure that solves it, because that is midnight UTC, not midnight local time.