# Date issue in R

Tags: r, date, date-conversion

I have some data, for example:

```
Date        CAC Index
2014-10-10  4073,71
2014-10-17  4033,18
2014-10-24  4128,9
```

But when I put it into R with XLConnect library I get the following:

```
wb<-loadWorkbook(file.choose())

lp<-getSheets(wb)
data=lapply(seq_along(lp),function(i) readWorksheet(wb,sheet=lp[i],startRow=1))[[1]]
data[,1]=as.character(data[,1])

tail(data,3)[,c(1,4)]
                   Date CAC.Index
719 2014-10-09 22:00:00   4073.71
720 2014-10-16 22:00:00   4033.18
721 2014-10-23 22:00:00   4128.90
```

Why don't I get the same dates? 
In example:
I dont get 2014-10-24, instead I get 2014-10-23 22:00:00

Might it be an issue with

```
ttz<-Sys.getenv('TZ')
Sys.setenv(TZ='GMT')
```

?
Best regards

Comment: Did you use `as.POSIXct` somewhere? Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26280480/3521006) is helpful?

Comment: @beginneR Hi, no I did not use `as.POSIXct`.

Comment: Are you changing the time zone environment variable? Do you do that before or after you import the data? What is your time zone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it comes from importing data as GMT and converting it to your local timezone, which seems to GMT-2, therefore `2014/10/10 00:00` is set to `2014/10/09 22:00`.

Maybe you could solve this by specifying your tz according to OlsonNames() list or specify your date column is `Date` instead of `POSIXct`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it has converted the date string in the Excel to a Date object in R.  Try a str(data) to see what the types are in your data.frame (good habit to get into)

If it is a Date object, then you can use format to put it in the way you would like to read it.  Something like:

```
##assuming data$Date is a Date class object
data$DateFormatted <- format(data$Date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

See ?format for other examples.