# Converting a Date object to POSIXct with timezones

Tags: r, date, datetime

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26279711/convert-date-to-posixct) and in other questions, it's fairly straight-forward to convert a Date object to POSIXct -- with the gotcha from `?as.POSIXct` that dates without times are treated as being midnight UTC. For example:

```
> Sys.timezone()
[1] "Europe/London"
> d <- as.Date("2016-06-01")
> as.POSIXct(d)
[1] "2016-06-01 01:00:00 BST"
```

I have two questions:

1) Why UTC?  Wouldn't midnight in your current timezone make more sense, i.e. `2016-06-01 00:00:00 BST`?

2) Is there a more elegant way to get the actual midnight for a date than the following:

```
as.POSIXct(as.character(d))
```

By way of explanation, I have a function that takes a Date as an argument and then finds all the log events that happened on or after that date.  With the standard behaviour outlined above, I'm missing all of the events between midnight and 1 am, and so I'm having to add the `as.character` cast.

Comment: Try specifying your timezone during conversion: `as.POSIXct("2016-06-01", tz="Europe/London")`.  See `OlsonNames()` for the complete list of acceptable timezones names.

Comment: This works because the first argument is a character, not a Date object.

Comment: I think `lubridate::parse_date_time()` might be useful here

Comment: @NathanDay `parse_date_time(d, "ymd", tz = "Europe/London")` does the trick.  That's about the same amount of typing as `as.character` but thanks for highlighting that function.

Comment: `ymd("2016-06-01", tz = Sys.timezone())` a convience wrapper if you don't need to power or matching multiple or custom orders.